# svg to middle of div in ul tag

Tags: html, css

So I've made this `<ul>/<li>`, and I've made a `text` with a `svg` image beside it.
But as you can see, if the width of the `<ul>`, isn't wide enough, the text goes into two line, THIS is okay.
BUT the `svg image` is in the top of the `div`, and I want it top be `50%` of the top.

NOTE: the `style="width:300px;"` is just to make a default smaller width of the `<ul>`.

How can I move the `svg` down to the middle?

```css
#svg_dashboard_weather {
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul id="tog_nr-<?php echo $testJobId; ?>" style="width:300px;" class="list-group list-group-flush rounded" >
<li id="3_1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                        <a class="text-dark" href="testresults?dashboardIds=3,1,1" target="_blank">
                            <div class="overflow-hidden">
                                
                <div id="svg_dashboard_weather" class="d-flex" title="5/5">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="weather-sunny">
                        <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                            <g transform="translate(1.000000, 0.000000)" fill="#0b6aa2" fill-rule="nonzero">
                                <path d="M10.8,6 C14.1137085,6 16.8,8.6862915 16.8,12 C16.8,15.3137085 14.1137085,18 10.8,18 C7.4862915,18 4.8,15.3137085 4.8,12 C4.8,8.6862915 7.4862915,6 10.8,6 M10.8,8.4 C8.8117749,8.4 7.2,10.0117749 7.2,12 C7.2,13.9882251 8.8117749,15.6 10.8,15.6 C12.7882251,15.6 14.4,13.9882251 14.4,12 C14.4,10.0117749 12.7882251,8.4 10.8,8.4 M10.8,0 L13.668,4.104 C12.7487597,3.76983548 11.7780941,3.59925827 10.8,3.6 C9.792,3.6 8.82,3.78 7.932,4.104 L10.8,0 M0.408,6 L5.4,5.58 C4.65522041,6.20908528 4.02228249,6.95968473 3.528,7.8 C3,8.688 2.7,9.6 2.532,10.548 L0.408,6 M0.432,18 L2.544,13.476 C2.89665685,15.4110521 3.90525776,17.1655091 5.4,18.444 L0.432,18 M21.18,6 L19.056,10.548 C18.7161518,8.60491495 17.7054771,6.8426039 16.2,5.568 L21.18,6 M21.168,18 L16.2,18.432 C16.908,17.82 17.544,17.064 18.048,16.2 C18.552,15.324 18.876,14.4 19.044,13.452 L21.168,18 M10.8,24 L7.908,19.872 C8.796,20.196 9.768,20.4 10.8,20.4 C11.784,20.4 12.756,20.196 13.644,19.872 L10.8,24 Z" id="Shape">
                                </path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <span>1 - Config.SlaveMinimumReplyDelay</span>                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
```

I want is to look like this:

[image]

Comment: you can use flex for the container

Comment: @Sfili_81 `svg_dashboard_weather` already have the bootstrap class `d-flex`?

Comment: it's not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flexbox on container, in your case the div .overflow-hidden.
Order property is used to change order for the flex elements

```css
#svg_dashboard_weather {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  order: 2; /* this change order of elements */
}

.overflow-hidden {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;/* this 2 properties is used to center vertically and horizontally */
  align-items: center;
}

.overflow-hidden span {
  order: 1;  /* this change order of elements */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul id="tog_nr-<?php echo $testJobId; ?>" style="width:300px;" class="list-group list-group-flush rounded">
  <li id="3_1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
    <a class="text-dark" href="testresults?dashboardIds=3,1,1" target="_blank">
      <div class="overflow-hidden">

        <div id="svg_dashboard_weather" class="d-flex" title="5/5">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="weather-sunny">
                        <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                            <g transform="translate(1.000000, 0.000000)" fill="#0b6aa2" fill-rule="nonzero">
                                <path d="M10.8,6 C14.1137085,6 16.8,8.6862915 16.8,12 C16.8,15.3137085 14.1137085,18 10.8,18 C7.4862915,18 4.8,15.3137085 4.8,12 C4.8,8.6862915 7.4862915,6 10.8,6 M10.8,8.4 C8.8117749,8.4 7.2,10.0117749 7.2,12 C7.2,13.9882251 8.8117749,15.6 10.8,15.6 C12.7882251,15.6 14.4,13.9882251 14.4,12 C14.4,10.0117749 12.7882251,8.4 10.8,8.4 M10.8,0 L13.668,4.104 C12.7487597,3.76983548 11.7780941,3.59925827 10.8,3.6 C9.792,3.6 8.82,3.78 7.932,4.104 L10.8,0 M0.408,6 L5.4,5.58 C4.65522041,6.20908528 4.02228249,6.95968473 3.528,7.8 C3,8.688 2.7,9.6 2.532,10.548 L0.408,6 M0.432,18 L2.544,13.476 C2.89665685,15.4110521 3.90525776,17.1655091 5.4,18.444 L0.432,18 M21.18,6 L19.056,10.548 C18.7161518,8.60491495 17.7054771,6.8426039 16.2,5.568 L21.18,6 M21.168,18 L16.2,18.432 C16.908,17.82 17.544,17.064 18.048,16.2 C18.552,15.324 18.876,14.4 19.044,13.452 L21.168,18 M10.8,24 L7.908,19.872 C8.796,20.196 9.768,20.4 10.8,20.4 C11.784,20.4 12.756,20.196 13.644,19.872 L10.8,24 Z" id="Shape">
                                </path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
        </div>
        <span>1 - Config.SlaveMinimumReplyDelay</span> </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or without changind the order, but modify the order of elements in the html

```css
    #svg_dashboard_weather {
      position: relative;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      
    }

    .overflow-hidden {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;/* this 2 properties is used to center vertically and horizontally */
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <ul id="tog_nr-<?php echo $testJobId; ?>" style="width:300px;" class="list-group list-group-flush rounded">
      <li id="3_1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
        <a class="text-dark" href="testresults?dashboardIds=3,1,1" target="_blank">
          <div class="overflow-hidden">
            <!-- moved span here -->
            <span>1 - Config.SlaveMinimumReplyDelay</span>
            <div id="svg_dashboard_weather" class="d-flex" title="5/5">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="weather-sunny">
                            <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                <g transform="translate(1.000000, 0.000000)" fill="#0b6aa2" fill-rule="nonzero">
                                    <path d="M10.8,6 C14.1137085,6 16.8,8.6862915 16.8,12 C16.8,15.3137085 14.1137085,18 10.8,18 C7.4862915,18 4.8,15.3137085 4.8,12 C4.8,8.6862915 7.4862915,6 10.8,6 M10.8,8.4 C8.8117749,8.4 7.2,10.0117749 7.2,12 C7.2,13.9882251 8.8117749,15.6 10.8,15.6 C12.7882251,15.6 14.4,13.9882251 14.4,12 C14.4,10.0117749 12.7882251,8.4 10.8,8.4 M10.8,0 L13.668,4.104 C12.7487597,3.76983548 11.7780941,3.59925827 10.8,3.6 C9.792,3.6 8.82,3.78 7.932,4.104 L10.8,0 M0.408,6 L5.4,5.58 C4.65522041,6.20908528 4.02228249,6.95968473 3.528,7.8 C3,8.688 2.7,9.6 2.532,10.548 L0.408,6 M0.432,18 L2.544,13.476 C2.89665685,15.4110521 3.90525776,17.1655091 5.4,18.444 L0.432,18 M21.18,6 L19.056,10.548 C18.7161518,8.60491495 17.7054771,6.8426039 16.2,5.568 L21.18,6 M21.168,18 L16.2,18.432 C16.908,17.82 17.544,17.064 18.048,16.2 C18.552,15.324 18.876,14.4 19.044,13.452 L21.168,18 M10.8,24 L7.908,19.872 C8.796,20.196 9.768,20.4 10.8,20.4 C11.784,20.4 12.756,20.196 13.644,19.872 L10.8,24 Z" id="Shape">
                                    </path>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </svg>
            </div>
             </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to force the svg to be aligned right at all time?

Comment: without changing the order?

Comment: Yeah just because when i try our code, some of my `svg`, is right beside the text but i want it at aligned right, and the `span` left

Comment: Can use `justify-content-between`